# ETH 409: Was the most obvious sign of fatigue being a factor due to one of the pilots calling out “go around” when they were climbing after T/O?

Tags: accident-investigation, crew-resource-management, pilot-fatigue

One of the pilots yelled out “go around” x6. It looks like they were making a right turn when they should have been making a left turn. The controller informed them for the second time to turn left, and that’s when the callout happened. Is this the most obvious reason for fatigue being a contributor to the accident?

Comment: Have you read the full accident report? Your questions suggest either you did not read the report, or you have a poor understanding of the report. https://www.bea.aero/docspa/2010/et-b100125.en/pdf/et-b100125.en.pdf

Comment: I fail to understand what you are asking for. are you asking "what are the elements making the investigator think fatigue is a contributing factor?", "what were the most obvious signs of fatigue?" or "how much did fatigue contribute to the accident?" or something else. You may consider editing your question to clarify it.

Comment: @MikeSowsun no, I have not. Only a short small clip that gave me this info, and with no luck in searching I came here.

Comment: @ManuH I’m asking if the pilot repeating “go around” was what led them to think fatigue played a role here? Or did he mean go around like the other way? The only time I’ve heard such words is when the plane is landing.....so I’m just wondering

Comment: @Firefighter1 you should put your last comment in your question. It would help clarify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Go Around" call was a call for a particular power setting (TOGA) because the aircraft was in a stall condition (rapidly decreasing airspeed, high AoA and stick-shaker). This was not fatigue by the aircrew thinking that they were actually performing a "go around", the captain wanted full-power out of the engines and there is a button that does that.